# Plotting discrete dates in boxplot x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a candle plot using ggplot2 on financial data.

I use the rgdax library to retrieve crypto currencies data.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(rgdax)
require(quantmod)

candles <- public_candles(product_id = "ETH-EUR")
candles$candleLower <- pmin(candles$open, candles$close)
candles$candleMiddle <- NA
candles$candleUpper <- pmax(candles$open, candles$close)
candles$fill <- ''
candles$fill[candles$open < candles$close] = 'green'
candles$fill[candles$fill ==''] = 'red'

#Add Moving Averages
candles$ma200 <- SMA(candles$close, 200)
candles$ma50 <- SMA(candles$close, 50)

#Graphing Step
g <- ggplot(candles, aes(x=time, lower=candleLower, middle=candleMiddle, upper=candleUpper, ymin=low, ymax=high))
g <- g + geom_boxplot(stat='identity', aes(group=time, fill=fill))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=ma50))+ geom_line(aes(x=time, y=ma200))
g <- g + scale_x_datetime()
g
```

The problem I have is that the dates are continuous and I want them to be discrete. Thus the error message:

> Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I also want to keep the full time, with the hours, minutes and seconds.

I tried using as.Date from the zoo package with scale_x_date, but I have the same error.

Here is an extract of the data frame:

```
> candles
                   time    low   high   open  close      volume
281 2018-02-13 16:40:00 684.55 684.55 684.55 684.55  0.14481784
280 2018-02-13 16:41:00 684.55 684.55 684.55 684.55  0.04325781
279 2018-02-13 16:43:00 683.99 684.55 684.55 683.99  0.60137169
278 2018-02-13 16:44:00 683.98 684.00 684.00 683.98  0.43150033
277 2018-02-13 16:46:00 682.72 683.90 683.90 682.72  1.73803500
276 2018-02-13 16:47:00 682.51 682.51 682.51 682.51  0.01398156
275 2018-02-13 16:49:00 682.51 682.51 682.51 682.51  0.28122771
274 2018-02-13 16:50:00 683.00 683.58 683.58 683.00  1.52767648
273 2018-02-13 16:51:00 682.99 683.00 682.99 683.00  0.29247699
272 2018-02-13 16:52:00 683.00 683.00 683.00 683.00  0.02190716
271 2018-02-13 16:54:00 683.00 683.58 683.00 683.58  0.50166543
270 2018-02-13 16:56:00 683.58 683.61 683.58 683.61 11.81034652
269 2018-02-13 16:58:00 683.98 683.99 683.99 683.98  0.44021340
268 2018-02-13 17:01:00 684.17 684.23 684.17 684.22  0.53595431
267 2018-02-13 17:02:00 684.37 684.37 684.37 684.37  0.48513463
266 2018-02-13 17:03:00 684.43 684.43 684.43 684.43  0.05492116
265 2018-02-13 17:05:00 684.43 684.43 684.43 684.43  0.11513667
264 2018-02-13 17:06:00 684.42 684.42 684.42 684.42  1.12376641
263 2018-02-13 17:07:00 684.43 684.43 684.43 684.43  0.57568335
262 2018-02-13 17:08:00 684.42 684.43 684.42 684.43  0.34713259
261 2018-02-13 17:09:00 684.42 684.42 684.42 684.42  9.89238437
260 2018-02-13 17:10:00 684.43 684.43 684.43 684.43  0.07287131
259 2018-02-13 17:11:00 684.43 684.48 684.43 684.48  1.19321749
258 2018-02-13 17:12:00 684.47 684.48 684.47 684.47  0.22166553
257 2018-02-13 17:13:00 684.21 684.47 684.47 684.21  0.06647252
```

Here is the expected output:

[image]

Comment: Your error starts at the beginning of your ggplot section. I guess it is rather concerned to the `candles$candleMiddle <- NA` line than the time variable, since 'candleMiddle' it's the only logical of [lower, middle, upper] when you draw `str(candles)`. After I did something to this line (which was with absolute certainty not the right thing), ggplot yielded something, which proves this theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes in the code: `geom_boxplot` requires the middle value not to be `NA`,  so I set it to the mean of open and close, but it could be set to any other value rather than `NA`. Then, I also converted the dates to `POSIXct` to be used by `scale_x_datetime` and added a little formatting so the labels could be shown better.

With those changes I think it works now, I hope it serves.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(rgdax)
require(quantmod)

candles <- public_candles(product_id = "ETH-EUR")[c(1:250),] # Selected 250 to be able to see the candles
candles$candleLower <- pmin(candles$open, candles$close)
candles$candleMiddle <- NA
candles$candleUpper <- pmax(candles$open, candles$close)

# CandleMiddle has to be set to a value so candles can be plot.
# candles$candleMiddle <- NA raises: `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale``
candles$candleMiddle <- 0.5*(candles$open+candles$close)
candles$fill <- ''
candles$fill[candles$open < candles$close] = 'green'
candles$fill[candles$fill ==''] = 'red'

candles$time <- as.POSIXct(candles$time)
#Add Moving Averages
candles$ma200 <- SMA(candles$close, 200)
candles$ma50 <- SMA(candles$close, 50)

#Graphing Step
g <- ggplot(candles, aes(x = time)) + 
     geom_boxplot(stat='identity', aes(group=time,
                                                   fill=fill, 
                                                   lower=candleLower,
                                                   middle=candleMiddle, 
                                                   upper=candleUpper, 
                                                   ymin=low, 
                                                   ymax=high))+
    geom_line(aes(y=ma50, linetype='ma50'))+ 
    geom_line(aes(y=ma200,linetype='ma200'))+
    ylab("ETH-EUR") 

g <- g + scale_x_datetime("", date_breaks = "15 min", date_labels = "%H:%M",
                      date_minor_breaks = "1 day")

g <- g + guides(linetype=guide_legend(title=''), fill=FALSE) # Remove 'fill' legend and just leave the one for the MA

g
```

[image]